# Add dynamic validation text to custom jQuery validation rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've written a jQuery validation rule that displays a failed validation if the amount entered into the input is less than 5000 or more than 500000. I'm trying to set the validation message to a variable to be dynamic in the rule but I'm getting an error saying I haven't defined my validationMessage variable.

```
# Error
Uncaught ReferenceError: validationMessage is not defined

# Custom Rule
$.validator.addMethod("requestAmount", function(value, element) {
  var cleanAmount = value.replace(/\,/g,'');
  var validationMessage = '';
  console.log(cleanAmount)
  if (cleanAmount < 5000) {
    var validationMessage = 'Please enter an amount greater than $5,000.00';
    return false;
  } else if (cleanAmount > 500000) {
    var validationMessage = 'Please enter an amount less than $500,000.00';
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  };
}, validationMessage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `var validationMessage` outside the function scope and remove the `var` from each time you set value to `validationMessage`:

```
var validationMessage;

# Custom Rule
$.validator.addMethod("requestAmount", function(value, element) {
  var cleanAmount = value.replace(/\,/g,'');
  validationMessage = '';
  console.log(cleanAmount)
  if (cleanAmount < 5000) {
    validationMessage = 'Please enter an amount greater than $5,000.00';
    return false;
  } else if (cleanAmount > 500000) {
    validationMessage = 'Please enter an amount less than $500,000.00';
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  };
}, function(){return validationMessage;});
```

Comment: Ok I removed the vars from the function (makes sense). I also moved the var = validationMessage outside of the function. Now it's not showing blank messages for the validation- as if the variable isn't being reset in the function. Should I pass the variable into the function as an argument?

Comment: Yes, on the last row you send the validationMessage before you change it, so create the function(validationMessage) to solve the problem

Comment: I copy and pasted your solution to double check but I'm getting: Warning: No message defined for object_name[amount]

Comment: I don't really understand the code you added.. function() {return validationMessage;}) but it works. I'll have to dig into why this works.

Comment: When was there validationMessage, you send him as his before function(value, element) executed, but when there is a function, u send the function and it  run after function(value, element) executed so you get the updated value.